# from set R, find the two closest nodes to the nodes in set P

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, distance

The code below should be completely reproducible. I tried my best to make question is clear, if not please ask for clarification.

What I need to do:

"From set `R`, find the two closest nodes to the nodes in set `P` Call the closest node `i` and the next closest node `j`" - quoting page 157 end of paragraph that starts step 2, in [this paper](https://www.scirp.org/pdf/AJOR20120200001_58723973.pdf).

The list `R` is the ordered set of nodes in a graph and `P` contains sublists of nodes assigned to a particular vehicle. For example

```
R = [1,5,6,9] # Size of R might change for new k
P = [[4],[7,3,8],[2]] # Sizes of sublists might change for new k
```

So vehicle `k=0` takes gets node `P[0]= [4]`, vehicle `k=1` gets nodes `P[1] = [7,3,8]` and vehicle `k=2` gets node `P[2] = [2]`. For each sublist in `P`, I want to find the two closest nodes in `R` from `P[k]`.

The distances are stored in a dict:

```
dist =
{(1,4) : 52.35456045083369,
 (5,4) : 37.48332962798263,
 (6,4) : 52.92447448959697,
 (9,4) : 76.83749084919418,
 (1,7) : 94.89467845985885,
 (1,3) : 58.9406481131655,
 (1,8) : 11.180339887498949,
 (5,7) : 54.817880294662984,
 (5,3) : 51.478150704935004,
 (5,8) : 45.044422518220834,
 (6,7) : 27.80287754891569,
 (6,3) : 60.74537019394976,
 (6,8) : 72.3671196055225,
 (9,7) : 99.68951800465283,
 (9,3) : 44.68780594300866,
 (9,8) : 15.811388300841896,
 (1,2) : 102.44998779892558,
 (5,2) : 65.60487786742691,
 (6,2) : 42.37924020083418,
 (9,2) : 102.55242561733974}
```

where the first element in the tuple-key are the `R`-nodes and the second element are the `P`-nodes.

So first `P[0] = [4]`, the two closest to this node in `R` are `i = 5` since the distance from `5` to `4` is `37.48` and the second closest is `j = 1` since the distance from `1` to `4` is `52.35`.

Now we proceed to `P[1] = [7,3,8]`. Here, is where I run into trouble. I interpret the paper as "which two nodes in `R` are closest to the entire group `[7,3,8]`?" My first instinct was to calculate the average distance from the `R`-nodes to each node in `P[1]` and the smallest value is the closest.

I've made an attempt, but it only works if `len(p[k]) = 1`. The function I need is a function that takes in `R` and `P`, and spits out `i` and `j` for each `k`. Here is my code:

---

```
for k in range(2):    
    all_nodes_dict = {}
    for i in range(len(R)):
                    all_nodes_dict[(R[i],P[k][0])] = dist[(R[i], P[k][0])]
                    min_list = sorted(list(all_nodes_dict.values()), key = lambda x:float(x))
                    min_vals = min_list[:2]

    two_closest_nodes = []
    for i in range(len(min_vals)):
        two_closest_nodes += [return_key(min_vals[i], all_nodes_dict)[0]]

    i = two_closest_nodes[0]
    j = two_closest_nodes[1]

    # do something with i and j before resetting them for new iteration
```

---

Here is my code for the function `return_key()`.

```
# function to return key given value and dict
def return_key(val, my_dict):
    for key, value in my_dict.items():
        if val == value:
            return key

    return "key doesn't exist"
```

---

Here is the code to generate **all** distances, or the `dist` dictionary in my code:

```
n = 10

random.seed(1)
# Create n random points
points = [(0, 0)]
points += [(random.randint(0, 100), random.randint(0, 100)) for i in range(n - 1)]

# Dictionary of distances between each pair of points
dist = {
    (i, j): math.sqrt(sum((points[i][p] - points[j][p]) ** 2 for p in range(2)))
    for i in range(n)
    for j in range(n)
    if i != j
}
```

---

Comment: How about analysing each node in `P(k)` separately and taking minimal distance to any of the nodes as a metric?

Comment: So what is the question? Do you want to find 2 minimal values for every combination from `[1,5,6,9]` to `[7,3,8]` ?

Comment: @matszwecja - I don't think it will work since I can't compare distances between P[k]'s like that. Eash P[k] needs its distinct comparison.

Comment: @Parseval I mean taking minimum instead of average within each P(k).

Comment: @AndrejKesely -  First I want to find the two minimal values for every combination from R to P[0]. After this, R and P[0] might change depending on some conditions. In the second iteration for k=1 I need to do the same comparison, i.e find to minimal values from R (whatever is in R now) to the ENTIRE group P[1] (whatever is in P[1] now). Basically, for the case k = 1, I want to find the closest nodes in R to the ENTIRE group and not one node at a time.

Comment: @matszwecja - Imagine it like this: You have four people in R. Which two of these four are the closest to the group of three people in P[1]?

Comment: @Parseval I understand it. Basicly you are suggesting to find a center of the group and calculate distance to this center, while I am suggesting finding a distance to closest person.

Comment: @matszwecja - Correct, to me it sounds like some nearest 2-neighbour from that center would be of use.

Comment: @matszwecja - That's atleast how I interpret the document/paper I linked to.

Comment: @matszwecja - Although, rereading that paper I get more unsure whether the correct interpretation is your way, or my way. That formulation seems ambiguous, or I'm simply misunderstanding it.